# Solve bad request error in USDA ESMIS API

Tags: python, python-requests, bad-request

I'm using the requests library in python to obtain data from [USDA ESMIS API](https://usda.library.cornell.edu/apidoc/index.html#/publication/createPublication) to no avail. I keep getting bad request errors.

In my terminal, the command:
`curl -X POST "https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token" -d '{"auth": {"email":"r******@gmail.com","password":"******"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

works as expected. However when I try the same using Python, I get a status 400 error.

```
password = getpass.getpass()
email = "*****"
data = {"auth":{"email":email,"password":password}}
headers= {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
URL = "https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token"
r = requests.post(url=URL,data=data,headers=headers)
r.status_code
```

I also tried parsing as `json` instead of `data` and with other headers. This is the first time I'm using the requests library so I'm probably missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

try using the `json` parameter rather than the `data` parameter.

```
requests.post(url=URL, json=data, headers=headers)
```